# Why does Lookup<TKey, TValue>.Grouping class not provide equality overrides?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have a scenario where the [`IEnumerable.SequenceEqual`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Core/R/9bdd6ef7ba6a5615.html) extension method is returning false when I was not expecting it to - to be precise, when using it to compare two sets of (known identical) [`ILookup<int, int>`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Core/R/2204d628fad521d7.html). Via the debugger, I discovered that the actual elements in my two collections are instances of the [`Lookup<TKey, TElement>.Grouping`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Core/R/cb695d4a973ef608.html) class, so I dived into the reference source.

To cut a long story short, the default equality comparer used by `SequenceEqual` is an [`ObjectEqualityComparer`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/ac282b3e1817bb9b.html), which defaults to using standard `Object.Equals`. But **`Lookup<TKey, TElement>.Grouping` doesn't override `Equals`**, so the `ObjectEqualityComparer` ends up using the default `Object.Equals` method, which calls into [`RuntimeHelpers.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edy4ke1e(v=vs.110).aspx), which (I presume, since it's `extern`) is doing a reference comparison and returning false.

I don't see any good reason why the bolded part should be true, hence this question. Does anyone know (or can explain) if this was a deliberate design decision (and if so, why) - or if it's simply an unintended omission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Publically, `Lookup<TKey, TElement>.Grouping` is just an `IEnumerable<TElement>`.

In general, two `IEnumerable<TElement>` instances are *not* equal just because their elements are equal.

Why should this particular implementation of `IEnumerable<TElement>` be different?

Comment: "... two IEnumerable<TElement> instances are not equal just because their elements are equal. Why should this particular implementation of IEnumerable<TElement> be different?" When you put it in those terms, it makes complete sense.

Answer (score 1):

No collection in the BCL overrides the equality members. This is the **convention** they stick to.

Why? Speculation: The performance profile could be surprising. Or, they thought reference comparison would be more useful. Or, they found it to be impossible to define proper equality everywhere (e.g. `MatchCollection`). So they decided to at least be **consistent**.

I don't see any reason why `IGrouping` would be an especially useful candidate to have equality methods on. It is pretty much as useful to have that as with any other collection.

Write yourself a `CollectionEqualityComparer<T>` and reuse it everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If a class is mutable, any particular variable or storage location of that type may encapsulate any of several things:

1. The only reference anywhere in the universe to an instance of that class.
2. A reference to an instance of that class which everyone is forbidden from modifying.
3. A reference to an instance of that class to which other references may exist, but which is owned by the owner of the variable or storage location and will not be modified without the owner's knowledge.
4. A reference to an instance of that class which is owned by someone else, and may be modified without the knowledge of the owner of the variable or storage location.

In the first two cases, value-based equivalence would generally be appropriate.  In the third case, it may or may not be appropriate (depending upon the semantic significance of outside references).  In the fourth case, value-based equivalence would be inappropriate.

Unfortunately, even though nearly all variables and storage locations could be easily classified into one of the above categories by the person writing the code, there is no defined mechanism for making that information available to the compiler nor the Runtime.  Consequently, there is no mechanism by which value-based equivalence could be used when appropriate without it also being employed when inappropriate.